# Current iOS Spyware/Stalkerware Capabilities

Tags: iphone, risk-management, spyware, fraud

I have a child domestic violence victim I am trying to collect evidence from and coordinate relief for (remotely), but I have cause to believe her phone and/or identity has been hijacked in the past to sabotage her escape options and paint her as non-credible ahead of law enforcement intervention.

In addition the suspect used to neurotically hover in the background during any sort of questioning of the child-- but as of late he is conspicuously absent. I fear he no longer *needs* to hover because he is secure in the knowledge that he can maintain proximity through more covert methods-- like bugging her phone.

What is unknown is *how* this was achieved; the most likely method was direct physical access but the suspect in question has mentioned the topics of listening devices and paranoia in other contexts so I'm considering the possibility of spyware on the victim's device given his unjustified familiarity with these subjects.

He is not savvy enough to have planted microphones or cameras and rigged up an independent recording solution, but dropping zero-config commodity stalkerware on the phone while she showers or sleeps and recording to the cloud is consistent with his skillset.

What I am unclear on are the current capabilities of commodity iOS stalkerware. Obviously anything is possible in *theory* with a persistent app, but I need to bet on what is most *likely* since I can't examine the device myself and don't want to freak the victim out or put the aggressor on notice by having the victim poke around menus they don't normally use. Resetting the phone will absolutely arouse his attention. I can't send her a burner-- he "accidentally" opens all of her mail.

I do not know if the device is jailbroken. Resources to achieve this *are* accessible, and I could see this service being requested during any of the numerous screen-repair jobs the phone has needed.

- Does anything exist that "captures" text messages from select senders and requires allow/deny from the monitor to let it through?
- Does anything exist that would let a remote observer intercept *and respond* to messages without the victim knowing?
- Does anything on the market capture or relay video calls? I'm especially concerned about eavesdropping of "private" conversations conducted over telehealth.

If I have some clue as to specific apps to look for, I'd feel more comfortable walking the victim through a targeted search for them.

He is all about masquerading abuse as "care," so anything marketed for the purpose of "protecting your children" would be of interest.

Any other advice/considerations? Is there a "tamper-proof" phone I could try to have smuggled to her?

Despite the risks I'm considering giving this child a crash course in encryption, one-time pads and relaying messages through carrier pigeon (if I can even get a hold of her). Everything else about her case for the last decade screams of premeditation of insurance fraud; she will likely meet an "accidental" death next year.

Any advice concerning who (besides the useless police and child protective services) I might be able to tip off about this would also be appreciated. I want to *prevent* this outcome, not retain the right to say "I told you so." Considering the FBI given the scope of other insurance-related fraud concerns in this case.

Thanks

Comment: This really isn't the best place for you to get the help you need. The question has a ton of different questions and you've asked for various lists. You need to have a long conversation with an expert and not a post on a Q&A site. ***And why on earth are law enforcement and child protection not already involved?*** Contact them, not strangers on the Internet.

Comment: Since you say that the phone could have been handed to an expert during "screen repair", then all bets are off as to what level of skill is required, right? Therefore, any of the functions you list are possible.

Comment: I'm also confused. You say that you want to give the child a crash course in raising pigeons, but simply doing a factory reset is off the table?